# Time-dependent tests, how to ensure success?

Tags: java, time, testng, mockito

This is probably a timeless question from someone who has not taken the time yet to fully investigate the problem at hand yet, but here goes...

The test is this:

```
@Test
public void expiryWorksAsExpected()
    throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    final MessageSource source2 = mock(MessageSource.class);
    final MessageSource source3 = mock(MessageSource.class);

    when(loader.load(any(Locale.class)))
        .thenReturn(source)
        .thenReturn(source2)
        .thenReturn(source3);

    final MessageSourceProvider provider = builder.setLoader(loader)
        .setExpiryTime(10L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();

    final MessageSource first = provider.getMessageSource(Locale.ROOT);
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50L);
    final MessageSource second = provider.getMessageSource(Locale.ROOT);
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50L);
    final MessageSource third = provider.getMessageSource(Locale.ROOT);

    verify(loader, times(3)).load(Locale.ROOT); // HERE

    assertSame(first, source);
    assertSame(second, source2);
    assertSame(third, source3);
}
```

At the point marked `HERE` the test fails... From time to time (pun intended). But I don't understand why. So, I'll unroll the code here.

First: `source` is a `mock(MessageSource.class)` (define test class wise), and the `MessageSource` code is as follows:

```
public interface MessageSource
{
    String getKey(final String key);
}
```

Second: `loader` is a `mock(MessageSourceLoader.class)`, which is:

```
public interface MessageSourceLoader
{
    MessageSource load(final Locale locale)
        throws IOException;
}
```

Third: `builder` is a `LoadingMessageSourceProvider.Builder`; full code below, with comments stripped (still a VERY long read, sorry for that):

```
@ThreadSafe
public final class LoadingMessageSourceProvider
    implements MessageSourceProvider
{
    private static final ThreadFactory THREAD_FACTORY = new ThreadFactory()
    {
        private final ThreadFactory factory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(final Runnable r)
        {
            final Thread ret = factory.newThread(r);
            ret.setDaemon(true);
            return ret;
        }
    };

    // From a custom API -- more details on demand
    private static final InternalBundle BUNDLE = InternalBundle.getInstance();

    private static final int NTHREADS = 3;

    private final ExecutorService service
        = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREADS, THREAD_FACTORY);

    private final MessageSourceLoader loader;
    private final MessageSource defaultSource;

    private final long timeoutDuration;
    private final TimeUnit timeoutUnit;

    private final AtomicBoolean expiryEnabled;
    private final long expiryDuration;
    private final TimeUnit expiryUnit;

    private final Map<Locale, FutureTask<MessageSource>> sources
        = new HashMap<Locale, FutureTask<MessageSource>>();

    private LoadingMessageSourceProvider(final Builder builder)
    {
        loader = builder.loader;
        defaultSource = builder.defaultSource;

        timeoutDuration = builder.timeoutDuration;
        timeoutUnit = builder.timeoutUnit;

        expiryDuration =  builder.expiryDuration;
        expiryUnit = builder.expiryUnit;
        expiryEnabled = new AtomicBoolean(expiryDuration == 0L);
    }

    public static Builder newBuilder()
    {
        return new Builder();
    }

    @Override
    public MessageSource getMessageSource(final Locale locale)
    {
        if (!expiryEnabled.getAndSet(true))
            setupExpiry(expiryDuration, expiryUnit);

        FutureTask<MessageSource> task;

        synchronized (sources) {
            task = sources.get(locale);
            if (task == null) {
                task = loadingTask(locale);
                sources.put(locale, task);
                service.execute(task);
            }
        }

        try {
            final MessageSource source = task.get(timeoutDuration, timeoutUnit);
            return source == null ? defaultSource : source;
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return defaultSource;
        } catch (ExecutionException ignored) {
            return defaultSource;
        } catch (TimeoutException ignored) {
            return defaultSource;
        } catch (CancellationException ignored) {
            return defaultSource;
        }
    }

    private FutureTask<MessageSource> loadingTask(final Locale locale)
    {
        return new FutureTask<MessageSource>(new Callable<MessageSource>()
        {
            @Override
            public MessageSource call()
                throws IOException
            {
                return loader.load(locale);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupExpiry(final long duration, final TimeUnit unit)
    {
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                final List<FutureTask<MessageSource>> tasks;
                synchronized (sources) {
                    tasks = new ArrayList<FutureTask<MessageSource>>(
                        sources.values());
                    sources.clear();
                }
                for (final FutureTask<MessageSource> task: tasks)
                    task.cancel(true);
            }
        };
        // Overkill?
        final ScheduledExecutorService scheduled
            = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, THREAD_FACTORY);
        scheduled.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, duration, duration, unit);
    }

    public static final class Builder
    {
        private MessageSourceLoader loader;
        private MessageSource defaultSource;
        private long timeoutDuration = 1L;
        private TimeUnit timeoutUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
        private long expiryDuration = 10L;
        private TimeUnit expiryUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES;

        private Builder()
        {
        }

        public Builder setLoader(final MessageSourceLoader loader)
        {
            BUNDLE.checkNotNull(loader, "cfg.nullLoader");
            this.loader = loader;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setDefaultSource(final MessageSource defaultSource)
        {
            BUNDLE.checkNotNull(defaultSource, "cfg.nullDefaultSource");
            this.defaultSource = defaultSource;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setLoadTimeout(final long duration, final TimeUnit unit)
        {
            BUNDLE.checkArgument(duration > 0L, "cfg.nonPositiveDuration");
            BUNDLE.checkNotNull(unit, "cfg.nullTimeUnit");
            timeoutDuration = duration;
            timeoutUnit = unit;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setExpiryTime(final long duration, final TimeUnit unit)
        {
            BUNDLE.checkArgument(duration > 0L, "cfg.nonPositiveDuration");
            BUNDLE.checkNotNull(unit, "cfg.nullTimeUnit");
            expiryDuration = duration;
            expiryUnit = unit;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder neverExpires()
        {
            expiryDuration = 0L;
            return this;
        }

        public MessageSourceProvider build()
        {
            BUNDLE.checkArgument(loader != null, "cfg.noLoader");
            return new LoadingMessageSourceProvider(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem: from time to time, I see the test fail; more specifically, at the line where it checks that the loader has been called exactly three times. Notwithstanding the fact that I have never seen the test fail before, that millisecond delays may be too short etc etc, I'd like to ensure that such a test runs and succeeds -- I want to test my logic. How do I do that without resorting to a 10 ms expiry time and an unreasonable (say, 2 seconds) sleep between fetches?

**EDIT** The purpose of the test is to validate that expiry times are obeyed; here I set a loader with a 10 ms expiry, and try to read from it a first time, then pause 50 ms, read a second time, then pause 50 ms, then read a third time; I want to ensure that the expiry works as I intend using mockito's chained `.thenReturn()` invocations

Comment: Can you please explain in a sentence or short paragraph the expected logic of what you're testing?

Comment: Haven't read the whole thing, but can you use dependency injection to control your application's perception of time independently of actual time passing?

Comment: @chrylis see post edit (at the end) -- I acknowledge that the post is too long, but I cannot, at the moment, see a more concise and explanative way to express the need at hand :/

Comment: @user2357112 uh, I'd like some pointers on how to do that... It may be interesting...

Comment: I would be surprised if this is possible at all non-flakily.

Comment: I can't find the article I was looking for, but you'd basically have objects depend on some sort of Clock object to tell them what time it is, and then for unit tests, you'd pass in a Clock that lets you set the time instead of working off of actual system time.

Comment: @fge @user2357112 Basically, you'd have to inject a `TimeService` that wrapped the clock, but this wouldn't work if you were using JRE libraries with timeout parameters.

Comment: Are you running the tests in parallel? I ask because it looks like you share the builder object between multiple tests which could result in your provider having a different loader than you think.

Comment: @Sign not that I know of; this is a straight TestNG test class, with a `@BeforeMethod` setting up the `loader`, `builder` and `source` variables, all of them being `mock()`s of their respective interfaces

Comment: @chrylis care to elaborate? I cannot find `TimeService` in JDK 7's Javadoc...

Comment: @fge That's some placeholder `FooClass` you'd write yourself; I was just answering the question of how you'd inject timekeeping.

Comment: It seems to me that all the details about the time that are causing problems for you are actually testing the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method, not any code that you've written.  Are you sure you want to be testing the JDK itself?

Comment: @LouisWasserman then how do you test such things as `LoadingCache` for instance?

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle the problem alltogether differently. Using time directly in the code is just wrong. What you need is a TimeService. Then your problem will be very easy to solve, you can just mock the TimeService.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would separate out the concepts of message fetching (if I understand your problem correctly) and expiring.  So something along the lines of injecting an ExpirationPolicy.  During your unit tests you can control this discretely by providing a fake version that you can have complete control over.  In your production code you can use a TimedExpirationPolicy which will work on timers that you can test completely independently from this class.

Not only are you going to make it so your tests can be made less flaky, but you are better adhering to Single Responsibility Principle.